# React callback function does not work how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

On one of my react Components I need to use a callback function. The the construction of my site is like this:

```
<Mainview >
<Header />
<Main />
<Footer />
</Mainview>
```

In one of my Main Component I used this:

```
  const Produkt = (produkt, { zumWarenkorbHinzufuegen }) => {

    return (
    <main>
    // ...
    
    <input 
       type="button" 
       value="In den Warenkorb" 
       id="Knopfwarenkorb1" 
       onClick={() => { zumWarenkorbHinzufuegen(produkt.id) }} />
 
    // ...
  
 </main>
```

In the main view I used this :

```
    <Route path="/bambus-zahnbuerste" component={() => <Produkt id={produkt[0].id}
                name={produkt[0].name}
                bild={produkt[0].bild}
                preis={produkt[0].preis}
                zumWarenkorbHinzufuegen={zumwarenkorb} />} />
```

The function "zumwarenkorb" is also defined in the `<Mainview />`

So when I click the button on my `<Produkt />` Component I get the following error:

```
TypeError: zumWarenkorbHinzufuegen is not a function. (In 'zumWarenkorbHinzufuegen(produkt.id)', 'zumWarenkorbHinzufuegen' is undefined)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your component's props are passed through the first argument of the Produkt function, or in your case the `produkt` argument. To access the value of the `zumWarenkorbHinzufuegen` prop, you have to unpack it from `produkt` in the body of your function:

```js
const { zumWarenkorbHinzufuegen } = produkt;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can destructure props in Produkt component to get produkt id and zumWarenkorbHinzufuegen function.

```
const Produkt = ({id,  zumWarenkorbHinzufuegen }) => {}
```

or you can keep the props and use like

```
const Produkt = (props) => {
  ...
  <input type="button" 
         value="In den Warenkorb" 
         id="Knopfwarenkorb1" 
         onClick={() => { props.zumWarenkorbHinzufuegen(props.id) }} 
   />
}
```